# Do I leave features with numeric categories as it is or create dummy variables?

Tags: r, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-extraction

I'm working with a dataset that has a combination of numeric features and features that are categories but encoded with integers. For example if it were a horse race,

```
horse_id   race_date    track_no        race_number    barrier_number  won_race  
1          2016-10-01   100             1              4               1
2          2016-10-01   100             1              3               0
1          2016-10-15   200             3              5               0
...
```

So, if I'm creating a model of a horse's probability of winning a race, and using the features like `race_number` (there can be several races on the same track on the same day so that should have an effect on track conditions) and `barrier_number` (a horse might prefer to be in the inside barriers or outside ones etc.), should i leave those features as it is or create dummy variables indicating 1 (presence) and 0 (absence) of the variable on each row?

This is a trivial example but these columns could have a large number of possible values and creating dummy variables will increase the dimension of the features a lot. Is that a tradeoff one has to make, or just leaving a single column do?

**Edit:** Also, if I leave the columns as it is and covert it into a caregory dtype in pandas, is that a good practice? Will existing ML libraries like Scikit-learn handle that correctly?

Comment: Numeric is fine, but their class should be a factor.

Comment: Not a bad question, but as you don't ask how to technically do this in R or python, it is better asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli thanks. will having a factor datetype or category in pandas work well when I apply them to ML algorithms?

Comment: @JanvanderLaan that is true. i'm working on pandas tho so I edited the question to be more specific since I'm not sure what the dtype of these columns should be (int or category) and whether ML libraries will work correctly with that.

Comment: @sfactor: datetype cannot be handled by any algo, so for that you could some valid data diff or encode them as beginning, middle, end of the months. AFAIK races held at the end of the month have high stakes. For scikit i think you have dummify the categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

For the features described (`race_number`, `barrier_number`) I believe it's perfectly fine to leave as is. However, for the example above, i would encode the `track_no` feature.

This is because there is no relation between the individual `track_no` values.

I would turn the above example to:

```
horse_id   race_date    track_100      track_200        race_number    barrier_number  won_race  
1          2016-10-01   1              0                1              4               1
2          2016-10-01   1              0                1              3               0
1          2016-10-15   0              1                3              5               0
```

I hope that helps!